# Where is Restlet's OAuth extension in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, oauth, restlet

I wanted to try out Restlet's OAuth extension in a Java EE project. When going to the [download page](http://restlet.com/downloads/current/#release=stable&edition=jee&distribution=maven) and selecting maven, a number of available extensions are listed, but the OAuth extension isn't.

According to the Javadocs, there is an [org.restlet.ext.oauth](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jee/ext/) package, but I don't know where I can find it in the Maven repository. It isn't in the main maven artifact, and there isn't any artifact whose description mentions "OAuth". Following the naming convention, I tried to add the artifact `org.restlet.ext.oauth`, but it doesn't exist (which is not surprising, as it isn't mentioned on the above-liked download page).

Where can I find the org.restlet.ext.oauth package the restlet Maven repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an OAuth extension in Restlet.

Perhaps can you try to use the Maven repository of Restlet. This link (http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/introduction/getting-started/maven) will help you to use this repository and configure the dependency within your file `pom.xml`.

You can see the extension in this repository. See this link for example: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.ext.oauth/2.3.1/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Well, I now found the problem: The download page I mentioned in my question seems to have a bug. When selecting "stable" a button apperas with the text "Download 2.3.1", but the maven code on that page contains `<restlet-version>2.0.15</restlet-version>`. Changing that to `2.3.1` fixes the problem.

Comment: Oh! I'll transmit your remark to the right person in Restlet to fix this! Thanks very much for the feedback.